# Matching order based on grouping variable

Tags: r, propensity-scores, matching

I want to match in a certain order.
I am aware of the argument `order`, available in package `{MatchIt}` - but this refers to the propensity score.
However, I want to match in ascending order using a grouping variable named `set`.
Thus, matching begins within the least value of `set`, 1:1, without replacement.

Some IDs contribute to multiple `set` values. That's why the order is important if I want to match without replacement.

Data and `set` variable:

```
library(cobalt)
library(dplyr)

lalonde$set[lalonde$treat == 1] <- sample(c(5, 10, 15, 3), sum(lalonde$treat == 1), replace = TRUE)
lalonde$set[lalonde$treat == 0] <- sample(c(5, 10, 15, 3), sum(lalonde$treat == 0), replace = TRUE)
lalonde$ID <- seq_len(nrow(lalonde))
copy <- subset(lalonde, ID %in% c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
permute_values <- function() {
  sample(c(5, 10, 15, 3), 4, replace = FALSE)
}
copy <- copy[rep(seq_len(nrow(copy)), each = 4), ]
copy$set <- unlist(lapply(1:(nrow(copy)/4), function(x) permute_values()))
combined_data <- rbind(lalonde, copy)
unique_data <- unique(combined_data)
```

Creating a formula for propensity score calculation

```
formula <- treat ~ age + educ + married + nodegree + re74 + re75 + re78
```

Calculate the propensity score within variable `set`

```
data_with_ps <- unique_data %>%
  group_by(set) %>%
  mutate(pscore = glm(formula, data = .[cur_group_rows(),], 
                      family = binomial(link = "logit"))$fitted.values)
```

Now let's carry out the matching.
This is my approach.
Argument `exact = "set"` does not solve the problem, because some IDs contribute to multiple values of grouping variable `set` and the `exact` argument does not include the order.

```
library(MatchIt)

data_with_ps_sorted <- data_with_ps[order(data_with_ps$set), ] 

m.out <- matchit(formula = formula,
                 data = data_with_ps_sorted,
                 method = "nearest",
                 distance = data_with_ps_sorted$pscore,
                 ratio = 1,
                 caliper = 0.02,
                 replace = FALSE)

mdata <- match.data(m.out)
```

As you can see, `ID` 1 has been matched 3 times, whereas it may only occur once. Since it was matched in `set == 3`, it may not be used again in `set == 10 or 15`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the first question you want to ask is "when a unit occurs multiple times in a single dataset, how do prevent it from being matched multiple times?" For that, you need the `unit.it` argument, which is documented in the [help file](https://kosukeimai.github.io/MatchIt/reference/method_nearest.html) for `method_nearest`. You need to supply `"ID"` to the `unit.id` argument so that once a unit with a given ID is matched, it is never used as a match again (note the documentation has a slight error; it applies to treated AND control units, not just to control units).

Now that that is taken care of, the next question is how to match in order of `set`. First, you need to order the dataset by `set`, which you did. But the next step is to set `m.order = "data"`, which will match treated units in the order they appear in the dataset (starting from the top). If you additionally want control units to come from the same set as each treated unit, you need to set `exact = ~set` as well.

So, your final call to `matchit()` should look something like the following:

```r
matchit(formula,
        data = data_with_ps_sorted,
        unit.id = "ID",
        m.order = "data")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive answer. I appreciate that! Assuming an `ID` with `treat == 1` also functions as a comparator if it previously had `treat == 0`(with the `treat == 0` observation). Does it make sense (because of argument `unit.id`) to extend the `ID`s which previously function as comparators with, e.g. `_1`, so that this `ID` is only excluded if it has served as a comparator?

Comment: It sounds like your matching problem is way more complex than a typical one if individual units can switch treatment statuses. `MatchIt` was not designed with this in mind. The way it is currently implemented, if any unit with a give unit ID is used as a match (either as treated or control), no units with that same unit ID can be matched (either as treated or control).

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try using my suggestion.

Comment: It works like that